# Python Tkinter PIL generate random 200x200 image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

In Python Tkinter [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324709/6929343):

```
# custom indicator images
im_open = Image.new('RGBA', (15, 15), '#00000000')
im_empty = Image.new('RGBA', (15, 15), '#00000000')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_open)
draw.polygon([(0, 4), (14, 4), (7, 11)], fill='yellow', outline='black')
im_close= im_open.rotate(90)
```

Generates a triangle in a format I can use:

[image: screenshot]

---

In Python tkinter [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864799/python-tkinter-random-generating-the-colors) draws on a canvas I can't use:

```
COLORS = ['snow', 'ghost white', 'white smoke', 'gainsboro', 'floral white', 'old lace' ...]

for x in range(0, 40):

    x1 = random.randint(0,400)
    y1 = random.randint(0,400)
    x2 = random.randint(0,400)
    y2 = random.randint(0,400)
    x3 = random.randint(0,400)
    y3 = random.randint(0,400)

    my_triangle = canvas.create_polygon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3,\
                  fill = (random.sample(COLORS, 1)[0]), 
                  outline = random.sample(COLORS, 1)[0])
```

However it creates desirable images:

[image: Tk Window Output 1]

---

The first code set generates an image in memory like I need but uses a triangle which I don't want. The second code set generates a canvas memory map which I don't want but has random shapes which I do want.

To improve the random polygon shapes in the second code set, circles and rectangles can be thrown in. Also the second code set contains color names  but random R:G:B channels would be preferable.

To select random shapes and colors the current `YY:MM:DD` or `HH:MM:SS` could be used. This is to generate random Album Artwork for home made music player when nothing is encoded to song or as a placeholder before real artwork is obtained.

In case it matters, platform is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, kernel 4.14.188, Python 2.7.12 plus Tkinter, PIL and Tkinter-Image (stuff).

Comment: What is your question? You've described what you want but haven't really asked anything.

Comment: @BryanOakley How do I make a random image to use as a tkinter label placeholder before I insert album artwork for my home made music player? Something other than a big black square or whatever.

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do. You say you want to generate a random image based on the date/time and show a block of code that doesn't use any dates or times at all? You then say colour names like "old lace" are *"too hard"*. Then you show some code that makes triangles and say you don't want triangles? Maybe you could give 2-3 concrete examples of what you do want? Then I am fairly sure someone can help you out. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've cleaned up the question hopefully it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate PIL.Image objects, with randomly generated:
shapes, fill & outline colors.

The resulting images are drawn to a tk.Canvas, for display;
that is irrelevant / for presentation purposes.
(The images themselves are in the requested format.)

```
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
from random import randint, randrange

# Create random indicator images.

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 50, 50
COUNT = 100

# Use datetime (somehow), to generate random int.
def datetimeToInt(): 
  y, m, d, hour, min, sec = datetime.now().timetuple()[0:6]
  return y + m + d + hour + min + sec

def randRgb(): 
  return(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

def randTriangle():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x3, y3 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]

def randRect():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)]
  return

randEllipse = randRect

# Map: random shape creation functions -> ImageDraw methods
shapeFactories = [
  (randTriangle, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon),
  (randRect, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle),
  (randEllipse, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse)
]
shapeFactoriesCount = len(shapeFactories)

imgOpenList = []
imgClosedList = []
for x in range(COUNT):
  # Get random index, within full range:
  #randIdx = randrange(0, shapeFactoriesCount)
  # Use random int, generated from datetime (somehow):
  randIdx = datetimeToInt() % shapeFactoriesCount
  shapeFactory, drawMethod = shapeFactories[randIdx]
  
  im_open = Image.new('RGBA', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), '#00000000')
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_open)
  drawMethod(  # passing 'self'/'draw' explicitly to method:
    draw, shapeFactory(), fill=randRgb(), outline=randRgb()
  )
  
  imgOpenList.append(im_open)
  imgClosedList.append(im_open.rotate(90))

# The rest is just for displaying the resulting images.

import tkinter as tk

from math import floor, sqrt

root = tk.Tk()

imgOpenList = [
  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) for img in imgOpenList
]
imgClosedList = [
  ImageTk.PhotoImage(img) for img in imgClosedList
]

imgsPerAxis = floor(sqrt(COUNT))  # rough approximation
canvas = tk.Canvas(
  root,
  width=WIDTH * imgsPerAxis * 2,  # x2: open & closed images
  height=HEIGHT * imgsPerAxis
)
canvas.pack()

for i in range(imgsPerAxis):
  for j in range(imgsPerAxis):
    canvas.create_image(
      2*j*WIDTH, i*HEIGHT, 
      image=imgOpenList[i*imgsPerAxis + j],
      anchor=tk.NW
    )
    canvas.create_image(
      (2*j+1)*WIDTH, i*HEIGHT,
      image=imgClosedList[i*imgsPerAxis + j],
      anchor=tk.NW
    )

root.mainloop()
```

Could you post the code that uses these images, as icons*?
(* in what looks like a tree-view, in your GUI)
(I'm curious, don't remember seeing custom icons there.)

[image]

---

If instead of individual icons, you want a composite image:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk
from random import randint, randrange

# Create random composite image.

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 200, 200
COUNT = 40

# Use datetime (somehow), to generate random int.
def datetimeToInt(): 
  y, m, d, hour, min, sec = datetime.now().timetuple()[0:6]
  return y + m + d + hour + min + sec

def randRgb(): 
  return(randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

def randTriangle():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x3, y3 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)]

def randRect():
  x1, y1 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  x2, y2 = randrange(0, WIDTH), randrange(0, HEIGHT)
  return [(x1,y1), (x2,y2)]
  return

randEllipse = randRect

# Map: random shape creation functions -> ImageDraw methods
shapeFactories = [
  (randTriangle, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon),
  (randRect, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.rectangle),
  (randEllipse, ImageDraw.ImageDraw.ellipse)
]
shapeFactoriesCount = len(shapeFactories)

composite = Image.new('RGBA', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), '#00000000')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(composite)
for x in range(COUNT):
  # Get random index, within full range:
  #randIdx = randrange(0, shapeFactoriesCount)
  # Use random int, generated from datetime (somehow):
  randIdx = datetimeToInt() % shapeFactoriesCount
  shapeFactory, drawMethod = shapeFactories[randIdx]
  
  drawMethod(  # passing 'self'/'draw' explicitly to method:
    draw, shapeFactory(), fill=randRgb(), outline=randRgb()
  )

# The rest is just for displaying the resulting images.
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
compositeTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(composite)
tk.Label(image=compositeTk).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try this after work. Do you have a sample of what image looks like?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Added sample results, for both cases.

Comment: Thanks for posting. To answer your question inside your answer those are expand / collapse icons for tkinter Treeview. They were created here in stack overflow in the first link in my question to deal with high DPI monitors.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Nice will check that out.